# How to refresh GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment() structure when reconecting display outputs?

Tags: java, swing, refresh, monitor

Problem:
Java/Swing application which shows separate `JFrame`s on every connected display.
I've found that display information from `GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()`
structure is invalid since the application start and the data are not updated dynamically
when new monitor is connected or existing one disconnected. Is there some kind of 
"force refresh" or "update" procedure for graphic environment during application run?

Answer (score 1):

The `GraphicsEnvironment` returned by `GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()` is internally cached and never created again.

What you may do is instantiate it yourself if you think the configuration changed. The class name of the `GraphicsEnvironment` implementation is stored in the `"java.awt.graphicsenv"` system property:

```
String className = System.getProperty("java.awt.graphicsenv");
GraphicsEnvironment ge = (GraphicsEnvironment) Class.forName(className)
    .newInstance();
```

But care must be taken because even if you will see the new configuration, classes of the standard library that use `GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()` will not know about this!

Answer (score 0):

@icza
Thank you for pointing me. 
I've wrote a simple code based on your suggestion for testing purposes:

```
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class GuiScreens {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     while(true){
        String className = System.getProperty("java.awt.graphicsenv");
        try {
           GraphicsEnvironment ge = (GraphicsEnvironment) Class.forName(className)
                        .newInstance();
           GraphicsDevice[] gs = ge.getScreenDevices();
           for (int j = 0; j < gs.length; j++) {
              GraphicsDevice gd = gs[j];
              System.out.println("Device " + j + ": " + gd);
           }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        }
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately does not work. What I've miss ?